# How to put currency symbol in jquery mask?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I made the mask work correctly on the `<td>` element of the table, but I want to add the currency symbol before the value, follow example.

```
if ($(this).attr('title')==='Value')
    { 
       $(+'R$ '+newValue)
          .maskMoney({decimal:',',thousands:'.'});
    }
```

Html code below

```
<td title="Value" class="editavel dt">converteValor(3500,00)</td>
```

The value coming from the bank is 3500.00 and I use the function in php

```
function converteValor($valor){
return "R$ ".number_format($valor, 2, ",",".");}
```

How do I do after the jquery edition continue with the mask 'R$ 3.500,00?' Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

```
if ($(this).attr('title')==='Valor')
    { 
       $(novoElemento)
          .maskMoney({prefix:'R$ ', allowNegative: true, thousands:'.', decimal:',', affixesStay: true});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet may be helpful to you...

```
function formatCurrency(total) {
    var neg = false;
    if(total < 0) {
        neg = true;
        total = Math.abs(total);
    }
    return (neg ? "-$" : '$') + parseFloat(total, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString();
}
```